Auth attempt allowed password field only in laravel
I am trying to login in laravel using this method
$password = randomPassword();
 if(isset($user)){
            $users = User::find($user->id);
            $users->google_password = Hash::make($password);
            $users->save();
if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $googleUser->email, 'google_password' => $password]))
 session()->regenerate();
                DB::table('login_log')->insert([ 'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,'time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'source' => 'Google']);
                return redirect()->intended($intendedUrl);
            }else{
                return redirect()->intended($intendedUrl);
            }

this type of user they will login with email and google_password
it will show error like Undefined array key "password" for the above code, How we can login with these details.
Please help...

Can you submit the whole code block? Because this piece of code will never generate that error.

Check the column name of the table.By default it should be password that is why you are getting error. Is it User model on which you are using Auth::attempt(..?

@DouwedeHaan code is updated.

@Subha the error is showing in the page  Undefined array key "password" and show the auth attempt line

Are you sure that User' model has a column named google_password?If not then change passwordtogoogle_passwordin theUser` model

why does your User have a google_password and not a password?

@Subha
yes i added the google password in model

@krisgjika
protected $fillable = [
'name',
'email',
'password',
'google_password',
'facebook_password',
];
these are my field if login from google i wand to manage by google password other that basisc

but where are you getting a google password from? if it's a random string how do you know what the password is when attempting to auth the user later?

@krisgjika every time this password is updated

@Laravelcoder use https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/socialite

@krisgjika ya, i already read that but i wand this type of method it's possible?

@Laravelcoder,In your code what is $googleUser? what this $googleUser returns.There is no code how you get $googleUser.

@Subha it's return from google after sucessfull auth it will return with user details
